# how to sign-in wso2 identity server use openid from other machine?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

1.i generate a new keystore use keytool(The info is [CN=192.168.0.184, OU=livechain, O=livechain, L=dalian, ST=liaoning, C=cn])
2.the identity server ip is 192.168.0.184 and i change the carbon.xml as following:

```
<HostName>192.168.0.184</HostName>

<KeyStore>
        <!-- Keystore file location-->
        <Location>${carbon.home}/repository/resources/security/mykeystore.jks</Location>
        <!-- Keystore type (JKS/PKCS12 etc.)-->
        <Type>JKS</Type>
        <!-- Keystore password-->
        <Password>mypkpassword</Password>
        <!-- Private Key alias-->
        <KeyAlias>mycert</KeyAlias>
        <!-- Private Key password-->
        <KeyPassword>mypkpassword</KeyPassword>
    </KeyStore>
```

and identity.xml as following:

```
<OpenIDServerUrl>https://192.168.0.184:9443/openidserver</OpenIDServerUrl>
<OpenIDUserPattern>https://192.168.0.184:9443/openid/</OpenIDUserPattern>
```

3.And when i want to sign-in the identity server on another machine that ip is 192.168.0.180,it occur an error as following:

```
0x704:I/O transport error:hostname in certificate didn't match: <WIN-L3NH0DVFLOG> != <192.168.0.184>
```

but if i use common sign-in with username and password,it successed.

4.I Never change the hosts.

So,how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Just to try out,  could you please change the  and  with 192.168.0.184  IP address.  And restart the server and try out.

```
    <OpenIDServerUrl>https://192.168.0.184:9443/openidserver</OpenIDServerUrl>OpenIDUserPattern>https://192.168.0.184:9443/openid/</OpenIDUserPattern>
```

Comment: Sorry, i forgot modify the ip in my question,but in my project,i had used the 192.168.0.184 instead of wso2.com and it also failed...